# Why it does not showing the year value .in D3plus scatter?

Tags: json, d3plus

I am using D3plus for data visualization . but in the x axis wrong data is showing instead of what i wrote in .x("year") to show .

http://jsfiddle.net/MituVinci/a77kz0dr/

```
enter code here
```

var visualization = d3plus.viz()
    .container("#viz")  // container DIV to hold the visualization
    .data(sample_data)  // data to use with the visualization
    .type("scatter")    // visualization type
    .id("Reason")         // key for which our data is unique on
    .x("year")         // key for x-axis
    .y("Female")        // key for y-axis
    .draw()

I also want to resize the width and height of this and also want to show it using an external json file how can i do it ?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Okay ,i will keep it in my mind , and sorry for my mistake :( .

Answer (score 1):

Since you have "Reason" as your .id() variable, D3plus is aggregating all data points that have the same "Reason". So the "x" position for "Family Feud" is 2010+2011+2012+2013+2014 or 10060, which is where all of your bubbles are located.

If you want to display each bubble individually, you could create a separate variable called "ReasonYear", concat the text of the Reason and Year fields together and then use .id("ReasonYear") for your visualization.

Use .width() and .height() to control the width and height respectively of your visualization.

Use .data() to load data from an external JSON file

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/alexandersimoes/d3plus/wiki/Visualizations